# how to include logic in JSX to convert object?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects populated by a webservice call

```
 const [items, setItems] = useState([])

 fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => setItems(json))
```

then I would display it as such:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      { items.map(item => {  
        return <pre> {JSON.stringify(item)}</pre>
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

The problem is sometimes that webservice returns a single object instead of an array, for example https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1

in that case I'd want to check if it's an object and if so, convert it to an array, by using [items].map

But how would I put that logic into the JSX as shown above?

Comment: The API should have a consistent returned structure. `/users/` will always return an array. `/users/NUMBER` will always return a single object. That should be enough.

Comment: Oh I know, just was wondering how to incorporate logic into the declarative systax of JSX for cases where it's needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      {(items instanceof Array ? items : [items]).map(item => {  
        ...
```

You could also do something above before you `return` such as:

```js
if (!(items instanceof Array)) {
  items = [items];
}
```